# FVA demonstration?

Tags: hedging, discounting, multicurve, xva, fva

In the well-known article by Mr. Piterbarg "Funding Beyond Discounting". he demonstrates that the price of a derivative product in a multi-curve universe:

[image]

Who also expresses it but without demonstrating it as:

[image]

How to demonstrate it, please?